# How do I set up Firebird 2.5.5 on my Mac?

Tags: python, firebird, firebird2.5

I installed it from the Firebird website, and running `import fdb` in python works just fine.  However, beyond that I have no idea what to do - I don't know how to set up a database, I don't know how to get to an SQL command line through terminal, and I can't figure it out.  I've been on google for several hours and it has yielded nothing. I really want to get this working.  I'm running OSX 10.11.1 with Python 3.4.

Comment: fdb is just the Firebird driver for Firebird, did you actually install Firebird 2.5.5 at all? I voted to close as you seem to request links to documentation and/or tutorials. You should start at http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ You should also consider posting your question to the firebird-support mailinglist as it might be a better venue for these type of broad/open-ended questions.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel yes, I did install Firebird as well as the driver.  I though that was self explanatory, but evidently not.  I'm not asking for a link, because, as I have stated, I spent literally hours on google looking for on myself.  I've seen all the reference manuals, as well at lesat 15 blogs and 20 videos of people attempting to explain it.  Stack Overflow is usually my last resort, because I always get someone telling me that my question doesn't belong.

Comment: Do you realize how broad your question is, without any specifics? You found 15 blogs and 20 videos and they didn't help you, then please help us and describe what is the specific problem you are having. Creating a database can be done using isql, as documented in the [ISQL documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/isql-create-database.html). You can also do it with database management tools like Flamerobin, fdb probably allows you to create one in code. But my guess would be that that is not actually your problem.

Comment: The specific problem I'm having?  I don't know what to actually do.  The Firebird manual things don't say anything about doing this on a mac.  I don't know how to create a database, I don't know how to get a window open that will even accept SQL syntax.  I don't know what isql is or how to access it.  I can't "get to a command prompt in Firebird's subdirectory" because I don't know what that means.  That's what my problem is.